# ParsePushBroadcastReceiver parameters

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm sending push notifications on my app using Parse.

I'm pushing it and inserting an object on my database. I need to get this object on database, I mean, pass parameter to parsenotification.

I have a class that extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver, now how can I pass and get parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Parse makes it easy to grab parameters from a push notification that you create in [CloudCode](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/JavaScript) or [from the client](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-data/Android):

```
//In your CloudCode function
Parse.Push.send({
    channels: channels,
    //where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      alert: "New Message!",
      badge: "Increment",
      title: "Your App Name",
      someCustomKey: "SomeCustomValue"
    }
  })
```

Now get the parameters from your `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` using the key names that you included in the `data` object in the push notification:

```
public class MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            JSONObject pushData = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("com.parse.Data"));

            String customValue = pushData.optString("someCustomKey","");
            String title = pushData.optString("title","");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v("MyBroadcastReceiver", "Unexpected JSONException when receiving push data: ", e);
        }
   }

}
```

Now you can instruct your application what to do depending on the values you supply.